# Autocorrelation function corresponding to density of states with significant rotational motion

Tags: statistical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, fourier-transform, correlation-functions, density-of-states

Most statistical physics textbooks (at least the ones I've found) state simply that the density of states of a system can be found as the temporal Fourier transform of the velocity autocorrelation function, and leave it at that. However, it's easy to see that this is untrue when the particles have rotational degrees of freedom: consider the extreme case where the system has modes whose particle motion is entirely rotational (i.e. translational motion is zero in these modes). These modes will *not appear* in the density of states if you define the autocorrelation function as $\left\langle\textbf{v}_i(t)\cdot\textbf{v}_i(0)\right\rangle$, because that only takes into account translational motion. So how should one define the autocorrelation function whose Fourier transform is the density of states in the case where the system particles have both significant rotational *and* translational motion, i.e. both $\boldsymbol\omega_i$'s and $\textbf{v}_i$'s (and a state with a given frequency will include both rotational and translational motion)?

NOTE: I realize that the reason why most textbooks ignore rotations in the autocorrelation function is because the particles are usually spaced far enough apart that the rotations are free and hence zero-modes in the spectrum, but I'm studying jammed systems where rotation is never free.

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to look at a (the?) paper where the relation is derived for insight into how to modufy the relation? http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.188.1407 Out of curiousity, what text books have you seen this relation in? I've only seen it in papers and was wondering why I hadn't seen it in a book.

Comment: I found the relation in the textbook "Computer Simulation of Liquids" by M.P. Allen and D.J. Tildesley, page 62.